# Spring - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager.getStrategies()Ljava/util/List;?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

After updating my pom.xml to use Springframework version 4.2.3 (from 4.1.2), the application fails to start-up with

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested except
ion is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager.getStrategies()Ljava/util/List;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
```

I've tried Maven Clean, rebuild, etc, but the error persists.

I suspect an old JAR is being held somewhere, but where?!

Comment: Can you paste your pom.xml. The only thing i can think of is you havent updated all the spring libraries. spring-web in this case.

Comment: Most likely you have an older version of a Spring library being pulled in as a transitive dependency. You should use the new Spring  4 Bill of Materials functionality to manage dependencies as it will prevent exactly this kind of problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26781484/1356423

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most likely you have in your lib an old version of spring-web-4.X.X.RELEASE.jar file. Just check that

Comment: I had to use the nuclear option. Deleting my local Maven repo (.m2 folder) followed by a full clean/rebuild on all projects and reset of Tomcat deployment fixed the issue.

Comment: For me this nuclear comment was a good tip, though I didn't blow away my local Maven repo.  In Eclipse I right clicked on the Tomcat server and chose "Clean..." option, then started Tomcat back up.  Worked fine after that.

Comment: @Nilesh it's related to what mariateresa said.  Say you deploy version 4.0.0 of the jar, then you deploy 4.0.1.  Sometimes you end up with both jars in your tomcat deployment because the old one didn't get cleaned up for some reason.  Now if you need something from 4.0.1 but tomcat is loading 4.0.0 first, then you get this NoSuchMethodError.  Hence the need to "Clean..."